# HighMaps Not displaying Country Data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts Js to display the Highmaps map bubble data. but the problem is that the Chart not plotting the bubble on Kosovo Country . For Example 
if I have a JSON Data as Follows .

```
[
 {"Country":"kosovo","persons":"2","CountryCode":"XK"}, 
 {"Country":"india","persons":"2","CountryCode":"IN"}
]
```

The Map is being displayed with only India Country Data. and shows nothing of Kosovo Country.

[image]

This is The Javascript i used :

```
var data_country = [{"Country":"kosovo","persons":"2","CountryCode":"XK"}, 
 {"Country":"india","persons":"2","CountryCode":"IN"}
] ;
data_country = data_country.map(function(el){
  return {name: el.Country, z: parseInt(el.persons), 'iso-a2': el.CountryCode}
})

Highcharts.mapChart('world-map', {
    chart: {
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
         plotBorderColor: '#ffffff',
         borderColor: "#ffffff",
         plotBackgroundColor: '#FFFFff',
        map: 'custom/world'
    },

    title: {
        text: "" ,
       enabled: false
    },

      credits: {
      enabled: false
  },
  exporting:{
    enabled: false
  },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
     mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Countries',
        color: '#E0E0E0',

        states: {
            inactive: {
                opacity: 1
            }
          },
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }, {
        type: 'mapbubble',
        name: '',
        joinBy: 'iso-a2',//'iso-a3', 'code3'],
        data: data_country,
        minSize: '4%',
         color: '#577ba8',  
         marker: {
              fillOpacity: 0.9
            },
        maxSize: '4%',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.properties.name}'
        }
    }]
 });
```

Please Tell me If I am missing something or is this an Highmaps error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using the unofficial country code, as it has no official ISO country code:

> The unofficial 2 and 3-digit codes are used by the European Commission and others until Kosovo is assigned an ISO code.

I also see that using `KV` in Highmaps seems to work. I'm not sure why they are using this partical country code. For example, from you code ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyzsta9f/)):

```
var data_country = [{"Country":"kosovo","persons":"2","CountryCode":"KV"}, 
                    {"Country":"india","persons":"2","CountryCode":"IN"}
                   ];
data_country = data_country.map(function(el){
  return {name: el.Country, z: parseInt(el.persons), 'iso-a2': el.CountryCode}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the Clarification. Your suggestion really works.